# Linux : Find last time when the machine was up

Tags: linux

I am trying to find out when was my machine was up last time.

Currently my machine is started at 11:00 pm. But i want to find when it was started last time(reboot/normal boot).

I tried using "last" command. but not getting any results.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try `who -b`? Because the man page states: `-b, --boot: time of last system boot`.

Comment: Difficult to believe "not getting any results". When does your `wtmp` begin`?

Comment: @mnille Thanks who -b is working. Any chance i can get the number of minutes elapsed between last login and now. means

Comment: I am trying to subtract who -b with current date.

Comment: @sampatnayak: This is just a suggestion, you have to tweak it to fit your needs: `who -b | xargs | cut -d" " -f 3- | date -d -  +%s`.

`who -b` => get date of last startup,
`xargs` => get rid of leading and trailing spaces,
`cut -d" " -f 3-` => get only the date,
`date -d -  +%s` => convert date to milliseconds since 1970.

Check the man page of `date` to find out how to convert the date in a format you need.

Answer (score 0):

According to the man page for the **last** command:

> The  files wtmp and btmp might not be found.  The system only logs
>   information in these files if they are present.  This is a local
>   configuration issue.  If you want the files to be used, they can be
>   created with a simple touch(1) command (for example, `touch
>   /var/log/wtmp`).

So, check to see if you have the file /var/log/wtmp. If not, then the information that you are looking for is not going to be available.